# How can I delete data from tags

Tags: c#, historian, proficy

I would like to delete data from chosen tag by time in Proficy Historian 5.5.

Can this be done using C# IHUAPI.cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible with IHUAPI.cs.

You could do this with Client Access API which is also available with Proficy Historian 5.5 and it's .NET based.

Here is a sample to delete data from a tag with a specific timestamp.

```
string[] tagnames = new string[1];
DateTime[] times = new DateTime[1];
ItemErrors errors;

tagnames[0] = "tagname";
DateTime timestamp = new DateTime(2016, 08, 01, 7, 36, 35);
times[0] = timestamp;
Connection.IData.Delete(tagnames, times, out errors);
```

Comment: I dont know why, but this function doesnt work. I try use it for different tags. I checked connection and its good, because other function like ITags.Delete work. Do you know the solution?

Comment: Could you give more details on 'it doesent work'? Exception? Any thing in ItemErrors object? Nothing happens?

Comment: Ok, It was problem with historian administrator... Restart helped.

Comment: Is it possible to get handle to the server in ClientAccessAPI?